# To filter the JSON files based on the timestamp

Tags: json, unix, google-cloud-platform, awk, google-cloud-storage

This is the bash script I was trying to use for filtration of files based on timestamps in buckets.

```
FILES=$(gsutil ls gs://bucket/*.json)
echo -$FILES
stime=01
etime=24
date=2021-03-28

awk -v a="$stime" -v b="$etime" -v d="$date" c="/^[[:digit:]]+/" -F "[: ]+" '
{
    if ($1 == c && $2 == d && $2+0>=a && $2+0 < b)
    print $3
}' $FILES
```

I'm getting a "No such file or directory" error, suggestions regarding this is highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you please eloberate what you are trying to achieve? Also can you please provide complete error?

Comment: The value in `c` looks like a regex — you should therefore probably use `~` to treat it as a regex in `if ($1 ~ c && …)`.

Comment: Also, if this is JSON, would you be better off using `jq` to do the query?  It understands JSON in detail — Awk does not.